# Jquery select ID to document select ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code.

```
function checkTracks( event )
{
    if ($("#form_1 input:checkbox:checked").length < 1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This works fine when it is on the same page (file) as #form_1 but when I moved it to sitefunctions.js it ceases to work. How do I update it, maybe with document select, so it works?

Best regards

Comment: pass a reference of `sitefunctions.js` in the html using `<script>` tag.

Comment: Assuming that you are loading this `sitefuntions.js` AFTER jQuery, it should work fine.

Comment: What error you are getting in a console? You may not refer the script file or the script file may be added before jQuery.js.

Comment: what about message in console ? any exception there? and also it seems that your problem isn't related about query dom selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file that you wish to use (sitefunctions.js) needs to be loaded after jQuery.